# Top & Left Navigation Bar Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to SharePoint 2013. I have a doubt about the Top & Left Navigation Bar.

- Do you have to be owner to modify it?
- If No, how can you modify it?

[image]

Reference of the image: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2082121&seqNum=5

Answer (score 1):

You have to be `owner` and need to go to `Site Settings -> Navigation` to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be having admin access to modify those.

- The top Navigation bar is nothing but the sub site names in the site collection;
- The Breadcrumb is the Document library Name and
- The left Navigation bar is the list of Lists and Libraries in the site